# SSRS Stop Converting Months to Names

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an issue in SSRS 2012 that is probably the easiest thing in the world to solve, but for the life of me I am lost on this one.

Background: I am creating a line chart in SSRS from a table that looks similar to this:

```
SELECT TOP 100
n.Node_Category_CP
,r.DateTime
,Availability
FROM ResponseTime r
JOIN NodesCustomProperties n ON n.NodeID = r.NodeID
WHERE n.Node_Category_CP IN ('Network','Servers','Voice')
AND r.DateTime >= DATEADD(Month,-12,(DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0))) AND r.DateTime < (DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

[Source Table - IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBg7u.jpg)

Now, I have created a Dataset in SSRS to load into my chart as such:

```
SELECT
    x.Team
    ,x.Month
    ,AVG(x.Availability) AS 'Availability'
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            n.Node_Category_CP AS 'Team'
            ,CONCAT(DATEPART(MONTH,r.DateTime),' - ',DATEPART(YEAR,r.DateTime)) AS 'Month'
            ,CAST(r.Availability AS NUMERIC) 'Availability'
        FROM ResponseTime r
        JOIN NodesCustomProperties n ON n.NodeID = r.NodeID
        --Last 12 Months
        WHERE r.DateTime >= DATEADD(Month,-12,(DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0))) AND r.DateTime < (DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0))
        AND n.Node_Category_CP IN ('Network','Servers','Voice')
    ) AS x
GROUP BY x.Team,x.Month
ORDER BY DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'1/'+x.Month,103))) ASC
```

RESULTS:

```
Team        Month       Availability
Network     2 - 2016        99.682518
Servers     2 - 2016        99.882986
Voice       2 - 2016        99.983606
Network     3 - 2016        99.213777
Servers     3 - 2016        99.997749
Voice       3 - 2016        99.953615
Network     4 - 2016        99.955140
Servers     4 - 2016        99.997766
Voice       4 - 2016        99.967692
Network     5 - 2016        99.940809
Servers     5 - 2016        99.663747
Voice       5 - 2016        99.464872
Network     6 - 2016        99.929164
Servers     6 - 2016        99.919462
Voice       6 - 2016        99.868244
Network     7 - 2016        99.853899
Servers     7 - 2016        99.999429
Voice       7 - 2016        99.968734
Network     8 - 2016        99.895597
Servers     8 - 2016        99.996016
Voice       8 - 2016        99.979156
Network     9 - 2016        99.925720
Servers     9 - 2016        99.990673
Voice       9 - 2016        99.901025
Network     10 - 2016       99.926707
Servers     10 - 2016       99.987152
Voice       10 - 2016       99.946401
Network     11 - 2016       99.708962
Servers     11 - 2016       99.968975
Voice       11 - 2016       99.863076
Network     12 - 2016       99.497376
Servers     12 - 2016       99.944684
Voice       12 - 2016       99.968642
Network     1 - 2017        99.543326
Servers     1 - 2017        99.980901
Voice       1 - 2017        99.960373
```

So, taking this data, I have created a simple line chart in SSRS using SSDT with the following points:

- Category Group: Month
- Category Sorting: None
- Horizontal Axis Options:

  - Axis Type: Category
  - Axis Interval: 1
  - Interval Type: Default

*Note that I have tried several variations of the Inteval and Interval Type with no solid results.*

Now, here's the problem, every single time, with any combination, the label returns as the Month NAME, without the year, and is sorted alphabetically.

[Preview of Final Chart - IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8GLY.jpg)

**What I would like to see is the numerical Month and Year (MM - YYYY) with the sorting order present in my Dataset results (Calendar order 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12), but I am 100% ok with seeing the month names as long as they are actually in calendar order...**

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd make it Year-Month instead of Month-Year... that way it will sort correctly.  SELECT [YearMonth] = CONVERT(CHAR(7), GETDATE(), 121)

Comment: sorry for the delay in response, but that is working perfectly. not ideal, but I'm not going to argue with results. :)